# Split a string into two separate attributes ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, split

I am performing a screen grab to get football results and the score comes as a string, 2-2 for example. What I would ideally like to have is have that score split into home_score and away_score which is then saved into my model for each result

At the moment i do this

```
def get_results # Get me all results
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
 days = doc.css('.table-header').each do |h2_tag|
 date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
  matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
  matches.each do |match|
   home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
   away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
   score = match.css('.score').text.strip
    Result.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, score: score, fixture_date: date)
  end
 end
```

From some further reading i can see that you can use the .split method

```
 .split("x").map(&:to_i)
```

so would i be able to do this

```
score.each do |s|
home_score, away_score = s.split("-").map(&:to_i)
Result.create!(home_score: home_score, away_score: away_score)
end
```

but how to integrate into my current setup is whats throwing me and thats even if my logic is correct, I still want the home_score and away_score to be assigned to the correct result

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT

Ok so far the answer is no i cannot do it this way, after running the rake task I get an error

```
undefined method `each' for "1-2":String
```

The reason .each doesnt work is because each was a method of String in ruby 1.8 and it was removed in Ruby 1.9. i have tried each_char, which now saves some results and not others and when it does save home_score and away_score are not assigned correctly

Answer

As @seph pointed out the each was not needed, if it helps anyone else my final task looks like this

```
def get_results # Get me all results
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(RESULTS_URL))
  days = doc.css('.table-header').each do |h2_tag|
  date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
  matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.report')
    matches.each do |match|
     home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
     away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
     score = match.css('.score').text.strip
     home_score, away_score = score.split("-").map(&:to_i)
     Result.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date, home_score: home_score, away_score: away_score)

    end
   end
  end
```

Comment: Is the method complete? Seems you lost one `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the each. Do this:

```
home_score, away_score = score.split("-").map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: amazing it works..why no each for this example, if you wouldnt mind explaining please

Comment: As you discovered, in 1.9 there is no each for String. There is each_char which acts like each(pre 1.9) and will step through the chars in the target string. You could write a routine to do what you want by saving the chars before the dash to home_score and the chars after the dash to away_score but split does that for you nicely(magically?).